# Increase HDD Space Sun Fire Server

Tags: hard-drive

I have Sun Fire X4250 server with 146 GB *4 (ST914603SSUN146G) raid strip hard drive installed , Windows server 2008 installed, in windows two volume created C 50 GB and D remaining GB,

I need to increase C volume space because OS giving me alerts of low disk space,
what is the best solutions to this case, is to add new HDD drives and configure as RAID 1 or extends space from D volume (no chance to extend more the 1.7 GB).

I have no too much experience in this field can u advice me and give me steps to overcome this case,

thanks in advance for any replay...
and sorry for my bad English...

Comment: I would determine what exactly is using your free space.

Comment: thanks @Ramhound for your reply , i try to find what is using my D space so it can not accept 'shrink' from Disk management and search about that found that maybe paging files of restore points that reserve that space